# On a puppet node, how do I see a list of resources?

Tags: linux, puppet

Given access to a single node that is being managed by puppet enterprise, I want to view the list of resources that puppet is managing. How do I do that? Node OS is Ubuntu 14.04. Interested in PE versions 2, 3, and 2015.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can see that on the client node in the resources.txt file.
See: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#resourcefile

It's located at `$statedir/resources.txt` so usually at `/var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt` or `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/resources.txt`

Answer (score 0):

just check the output of a normal puppet agent launch adding --noop

In the output you can see everything (including resources) that would happen without changing anything on your system.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I thought I remember a bug with --noop that would cause puppet to actually change things. I think this might have been fixed in later versions, but I'm working with some servers on 2.8 here. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/20679